# Retrieve day light saving time for time zone and date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, datetime

I want Daylight for passed date and timezone in SQL Server.

For example, I am passing TimeZone = 'PST' AND Date = '2020-05-20 09:41:55.130'.

I need daylight is applying for the current date to pst timezone out put 'yes' or 'no'.

Note: Time Zone and Date are dynamic.

I have C# code and it's working fine.

```cs
     public static bool IsDaylightSavingTime(string timeZone)
        {
            try
            {
                //if isDaylight is true in 'PST' then offset is -7 else -8

                bool isDaylight = false;
                DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime UTCTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

                string TimeZoneFullName = string.Empty;
                if (timeZone.ToUpper() == "PST" || timeZone.ToUpper() == "PT")
                {
                    TimeZoneFullName = "Pacific Standard Time"; //UTC−08 DST −07:00
                }
                else if (timeZone.ToUpper() == "MST" || timeZone.ToUpper() == "MT")
                {
                    TimeZoneFullName = "Mountain Standard Time"; //UTC−07  DST −06:00
                }
                else if (timeZone.ToUpper() == "CST" || timeZone.ToUpper() == "CT")
                {
                    TimeZoneFullName = "Central Standard Time"; //UTC−06 DST −05:00
                }
                else if (timeZone.ToUpper() == "EST" || timeZone.ToUpper() == "ET")
                {
                    TimeZoneFullName = "Eastern Standard Time"; //UTC−05  DST −04:00
                }


                if (TimeZoneFullName != string.Empty)
                {
                    TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneFullName);
                    isDaylight = tzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime);
                }

                //WriteLog(string.Format("{0} isDaylight : {1} ", timeZone, isDaylight));
                return isDaylight;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog(string.Format("Error while check Day light Saving Time. (Utility - IsDaylightSavingTime) \n TimeZone {0} \n Error : {1}", timeZone, ex.ToString()));
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: UTC has no daylight saving, so why are you using `GETUTCDATE`?. What are you even trying to ask here? This makes no sense I'm afraid.

Comment: it's an example@Larnu

Comment: I have passed date of pst time zone , on that time period daylight is applicable or not, that thing i want to know

Comment: So you want to know if a timezone observes Daylight saving or not? It's not to do with timezones, it's to do with location. For example, some states in the US don't observe it any more, meaning that some may be in CDT and others CST at the same time.

Comment: @Larnu i have done that code in c# but i need same functionality in sql server plz review above code and it's working fine

Comment: @rakesh6gvm Please add your c# code sample to your question

Comment: @VenkataramanR plz review above code , it's working fine i need same thing in sql server

Comment: If you want to know if a timezone is currently observing DST in SQL Server, why not consult `sys.time_zone_info`?

Comment: That sentece makes no sense.

Comment: @Larnu not working in my SQL server sys.time_zone_info   returning error like        Invalid object name 'sys.time_zone_info'.

Comment: `sys.time_zone_info` is available in all (fully) supported versions of SQL Server, @rakesh6gvm . What version are you using?

Comment: @Larnu  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17213.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.232
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.10586.0
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.10586.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.10586

Comment: What version of SQL Server, not SSMS, @rakesh6gvm

Comment: @Larnu 17.4, is it the possible to role-related issue of the guest user?

Comment: There is no SQL Server 17.4... the latest is version 15. If you did, however, get version 17 from.the future, it would have the object.

Comment: @Larnu Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17213.0

Comment: @Larnu I have connected with the server , maybe this problem occurring for that reason?

Comment: *"What version of SQL Server, not SSMS, @rakesh6gvm"*... The version of SSMS has nothing to do with the version of SQL Server you are using. It's like someone asking you what version of Windows you have and responding with "Excel 2016".